# How to change the Windows Phone 8.1 theme color

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making an app that could change color of phone theme(Accent colour),
but i'm not finding anything. Don't know if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot change system theme colors. You can only override them locally for your application and make your application appear independent of the current theme colors.